# Woocommerce PHP Fatal Error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am getting the white screen of death with my Wordpress site and I have narrowed it down to a .php file in my Woocommerce includes file. The error is as follows:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get_formatted_name() on a non-object in /home2/hatchchi/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-deprecated-functions.php on line 63

Here is what line 63 includes:

```
function woocommerce_get_formatted_product_name( $product ) {
    _deprecated_function( __FUNCTION__, '2.1', 'WC_Product::get_formatted_name()' );
    return $product->get_formatted_name();
}
```

I tried removing the file, the line of code and replacing the Woocommerce plugin manually via FTP but nothing fixed it.

What would be causing this sort of error? What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

By best to narrow these sort of things down is to try deactivating all other plugins and trying a default WordPress theme to see if that solves your issue.